# Android location getTime() always returns big different time

Tags: android, timezone, location

I am getting location using Location Manager regulary depending on the setting, 2minutes in testing case and trying to use location.geTime() method. I am not using LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(). Document says it is UTC time and I converted it to local time like below:

```
Date d = new Date(location.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddkkmmss';
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimneZone("UTC");
sdf.format(d);
```

But I am getting different date from what I expect. Current time I am writing is about 130516155000(2013-05-16 15:50:00) but I am getting 040015130515.
And I removed the timezone and set the time zone as 'GMT' as well and date fixed but time was quite different. In real device and emulator are same. And I already checked timezone setting in both and they are correct.
Please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I add more.

```
Log:
05-16 16:09:30.227: D/location.getTime()(1279): 1368590417000
05-16 16:09:30.237: D/NMEAGPRMCTime(1279): 040017
05-16 16:09:30.247: D/NMEAGPRMCDate(1279): 130515
```

Code:

```
public static String NMEAGPRMCTime(Date d)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kkmmss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String result = sdf.format(d);
    Log.d("NMEAGPRMCTime", result);
    return result;
}


public static String NMEAGPRMCDate(Date d)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String result = sdf.format(d);
    Log.d("NMEAGPRMCDate", result);

    return result;
}
```

That's it. This is the code exactly what I using.

Comment: It seems *very* unlikely that you'd get that output from that format - it suggests that the month is 0! Then again, the code you've posted is invalid, so maybe you're not actually using the format you claim to be. Please post *valid* code which matches the real code you're using.

Comment: Additionally, what happens if you log `location.getTime().toString()`? That will display in the system default time zone, but at least it would separate the problem of "what's the value" from the formatting.

Comment: @Jon Thanks. I added more and location.getTime() is not object, but primitive type, so you can't use toString().

Comment: Okay, sorry about that - try `new Date(location.getTime()).toString()`. The point is to get the result without the `SimpleDateFormat` part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the formatting here.

Look at the log:

```
05-16 16:09:30.227: D/location.getTime()(1279): 1368590417000
05-16 16:09:30.237: D/NMEAGPRMCTime(1279): 040017
05-16 16:09:30.247: D/NMEAGPRMCDate(1279): 130515
```

Using [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) you can see that the "millis since epoch" value of 1368590417000 is actually Wed, 15 May 2013 04:00:17 UTC. So a time of 040017 and a date of 130515 is exactly right.

I suspect you're actually confused by what [`Location.getTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) does - it returns the time of the fix, not the current time. So basically, that location was obtained at 04:00:17 UTC, regardless of the current date/time.

Comment: Thanks for your point. I have been investigating about what you are mentioning about. Now I know the problem comes from the reason. My location fix has timeout and it as not enough for GPS provider, about 30 seconds, and it gave old fix time.
Thanks to you and I can find to fix another bug.

Comment: @Jon can i know, What you mean by 'time of fix'? I am not getting about the meaning of that.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer: The time at which the location manager determined the location.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you tell us where does the time come from? e.g. the device clock?

Comment: @luizfzs: Yes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone--