# set Timestamp in onLocationChanged method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get  timestamp in the "onLocationChanged" method but without success. How can I set the timestamp with the aid of location.getTime in the "onLocationChanged" methode? Longitude and Latitude are being displayed.

```js
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (location != null) {
    double plong = location.getLongitude();
    double pLat = location.getLatitude();

   Date d = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
   String s = sdf.format(d);
   textTime.setText(s);

    textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
    textLong.setText(Double.toString(plong));

   }
  }
```

Comment: I wonder if timestamp work in Android, it is deprecated.  Did you try Date instead

Comment: see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579921/android-locatoin-gettime-always-returns-big-different-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply try this:

```java
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  Timestamp time = new Timestamp(location.getTime());

  textTime.setText(time.toString());
}
```

---

To specify custom output string format is's fine to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```java
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  String formatted = sdf.format(new Date(location.getTime()));

  textTime.setText(formatted);
}
```

Comment: My updated answer works well too but I want to use "location.getTime()" method. Is there any way to get ride of the seconds digits  from location.getTime() format? the current output of location.getTime() is "2015-04-05 23:17:26.0" with 0 digit at the end. With my code I can determin the used format for example "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"==> without seconds digits "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm" I want timestamp without seconds digits.