# Daylight savings can cause Location.getTime() to return UTC-1 on some phones, is this a known issue and is there a solution?

Tags: android, gps, timezone, gps-time

Based on the Android documentation the Location's getTime() method returns UTC of the time of a fix, so my assumption is that regardless of what the user does - changing the phone's time or timezone, will not alter this value, but this appears not to be the case on all phones.

The majority of phones we've tried have behaved as expected, but with a couple (both are running Android 4.4.2) when daylight savings are applicable e.g. BST (British Summer Time) then Location.getTime() returns values that are UTC-1. (there are other 4.4.2 devices that do behaviour correctly).

Is this is known issue and is there any solution?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579921/android-location-gettime-always-returns-big-different-time  .  Also good info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958640/location-gettime-always-returns-timestamp-without-milliseconds)